# checking if grep command returns correct output

Tags: bash, shell

Thing is that I am using `wget` to extract url after that I want to pipe it to grep to check if it matches some pattern and if it does simply echo name of url.

Something like this:

```
wget url |grep "pattern" 
if successful
display urlname
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` condition is true if its command returns 0. `grep` returns 0 if it matches the pattern to the input.

```
if wget -O - ... | grep -q ...
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: and for `wget` use `-O -` (and `-q`)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Good call.

Comment: If only there were some way to do a loop in the shell, a way to do insert the loop variable into the wget command, and another command that echoed the url name again... :-)

Comment: You mean like a function?

Comment: maybe a `for f  in ` or `while read line` type of statement, and maybe `$f` to print the variable name out

Comment: I read the question again and he doesn't say he has a list of these to check, so may be unnecessary.

Comment: This is basically equivalent to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184677/how-to-check-for-websites-that-implement-google-search#comment26680166_18184677) which the same user is now asking [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207533/how-to-check-websites-implementing-google-customized-search) while still stubbornly refusing to demonstrate any effort in explaining the actual problem, let alone attempting to reach a solution.